# VBA "Compile error: Argument not optional" debugging sub

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to debug this simple section of code:

```
Public Sub FunctionNotValidVarType()
MsgBox "VarType " & VarType & " is not supported. Please check spelling."
End Sub
```

Comment: Public Sub FunctionNotValidVarType()
Dim variable As Integer
variable = 2
MsgBox "VarType " & VarType(variable) & " is not supported. Please check spelling."
End Sub

Comment: And since `VarType` is a VBA function, which requires a variable to be passed to it as an argument, you get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub FunctionNotValidVarType()
Dim variable As Integer
variable = 2
MsgBox "VarType " & VarType(variable) & " is not supported. Please check spelling."
End Sub
```

You need to call the VarType function passing to it an actual variable

Comment: Public BrgSum, BgrVal, Volcorr, MEeff, VarType

Comment: Public Sub FunctionNotValidVarType()
    VarType = CStr(struserChoice)
    MsgBox "VarType " & VarType & " is not supported. Please check spelling."
End Sub

Comment: Public Sub FunctionNotValidVarType()
    Dim struserChoice As Integer, newvar As String
    struserChoice = 3
    newvar = CStr(struserChoice)
    MsgBox "VarType " & VarType(newvar) & " is not supported. Please check spelling."
End Sub

Comment: you are missing the point. VarType is not a variable name, is a VBA function. so you have to use it like:
variableyouwant = VarType (variableofwhichyouwantthetype)